# How can I create a csv importer in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have an application in which the database shows people information.

I currently import the data from a csv file through the following script:

```
import csv, sys, os
dir_projeto = 
"/home/danilo/Documentos/Projetos/transparencia/transparencia/"
sys.path.append(dir_projeto)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='settings'
import django
django.setup()
from pessoal.models import Pessoa

data = csv.reader(open("CC_JUNHO.csv"), delimiter=";")

for linha in data:
    importacao = Pessoa()
    importacao.matricula = linha[0]
    importacao.funcionario = linha[1]
    importacao.cargo = linha[2]
    importacao.data_admissao = linha[3]
    importacao.salario_fixo = linha[4]
    importacao.tota_bruto = linha[5]
    importacao.total_desconto = linha[6]
    importacao.liquido = linha[8]
    importacao.save()
```

However, is it possible to do this import through a view and a django template? Example: The template would have a form to add the csv file, in which it would be imported into the db by the view. It is possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can like you said create a form to gather your data. The form then performs a `POST` to a URL, which triggers a view that processes the data.

The following Django Tutorial elaborates this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/

For Example if your form sends a name, you can use the following to process it:

```
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: In fact, what I need is for the form to have only the field to add a csv file, and the data that is in that csv is imported into the database. 
I do not want to have to write the data one by one.

Comment: Then you should clarify your question. Your intent is not clear from what you wrote.